# integrating mpu9250 with imx6 board

Tags: linux

I am trying to use `mpu9250 3 axis accelerometer` with `imx6 board`. I have taken `invensense mpu 9265` device driver for `Android` from [here](https://github.com/NoelMacwan/Kernel-10.4.1.B.0.101/tree/master/drivers/staging/iio/imu), and successfully compiled the driver with `Linux 3.18 kernel` as a module (`inv_mpu_iio`). I have even changed `dts file` based on my requirement.

I have little knowledge about device trees but after searching I have done following changes to the `dts file`.

Edited `dts file` code snippet:

```
&i2c3 {

    extaccelerometer: mpu9265@68{
        compatible = "mpu9250";
        reg = <0x68>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
        interrupts = <9>;
    };

}
```

While booting the kernel on to the board I am stuck with the following error:

```
    [   10.730459] industrialio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   10.805020] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   10.819012] kfifo_buf: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...[   10.910701] inv_mpu_iio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been.
[   10.973279] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
[   10.981478] pgd = bdeac000
[   10.984286] [00000000] *pgd=00000000
[   10.987969] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] SMP ARM
[   10.992628] Modules linked in: inv_mpu_iio(C+) kfifo_buf(C) industrialio(C) sky2
[   11.000167] CPU: 3 PID: 333 Comm: modprobe Tainted: G         C     3.18.0i2c-test+ #1
[   11.008117] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[   11.014695] task: bdfc0000 ti: bdd16000 task.ti: bdd16000
[   11.020179] PC is at inv_mpu_probe+0x70/0xb6c [inv_mpu_iio]
[   11.025769] LR is at 0x0
[   11.028318] pc : [<7f029110>]    lr : [<00000000>]    psr: a0000013
[   11.028318] sp : bdd17c98  ip : bdc5b484  fp : bdd17cdc
[   11.039806] r10: 00000000  r9 : 00000004  r8 : 7f02fa34
[   11.045064] r7 : bdc5b400  r6 : 00000001  r5 : befd7800  r4 : bdc5b000
[   11.051643] r3 : 00000068  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 0000002f  r0 : bdc5b000
[   11.058250] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[   11.065427] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 4deac04a  DAC: 00000015
[   11.071241] Process modprobe (pid: 333, stack limit = 0xbdd16238)
[   11.077417] Stack: (0xbdd17c98 to 0xbdd18000)
[   11.081848] 7c80:                                                       bdd17ccc bdd17ca8
[   11.090093] 7ca0: 801b0764 801acc5c befd7820 8041d804 befd7820 befd7820 00000000 7f031798
[   11.098316] 7cc0: befd7800 7f031798 00000004 00000000 bdd17cfc bdd17ce0 8054ad94 7f0290ac
[   11.106568] 7ce0: 81589ca8 befd7820 80cf1758 00000000 bdd17d34 bdd17d00 8040e504 8054acb4
[   11.114854] 7d00: 8054ac94 80349964 7f031798 befd7820 7f031798 befd7854 00000000 7f037000
[   11.123142] 7d20: 8152cc60 00000000 bdd17d54 bdd17d38 8040e7f4 8040e3cc bef307e4 00000000
[   11.131438] 7d40: 7f031798 8040e750 bdd17d7c bdd17d58 8040c6fc 8040e75c bee18ac0 bef307d8
[   11.139705] 7d60: be7535e0 7f031798 bdd2b480 80ccc070 bdd17d8c bdd17d80 8040de9c 8040c6a4
[   11.147932] 7d80: bdd17db4 bdd17d90 8040da60 8040de80 7f030c18 bdd17da0 7f031798 80c76c58
[   11.156173] 7da0: be7f95c0 80cea230 bdd17dcc bdd17db8 8040f1f0 8040d974 7f031774 80c76c58
[   11.164408] 7dc0: bdd17de4 bdd17dd0 8054d384 8040f174 80c76c58 80c76c58 bdd17dfc bdd17de8
[   11.172629] 7de0: 7f037018 8054d354 00000000 80c76c58 bdd17e7c bdd17e00 80008b20 7f03700c
[   11.180852] 7e00: bdd17e44 bdd17e10 8013b4b4 8077f8a4 00000001 0000084f bdd17e44 000000db
[   11.189069] 7e20: bdf1b100 c0c70000 00000001 be7f9440 8152cc60 00000001 bdd17e64 bdd17e48
[   11.197330] 7e40: 801301d0 8013b26c bdd17f48 7f0320d4 7f0320c8 bdd17f48 7f0320d4 7f0320c8
[   11.205568] 7e60: 80cea230 be7f9440 8152cc60 00000001 bdd17f3c bdd17e80 800a92e0 80008a70
[   11.213776] 7e80: 7f0320d4 00007fff 800a64e8 bdd17f04 bdd17ebc c0c70000 00000000 c0d14dd8
[   11.221973] 7ea0: bdd17ed4 76f91d50 00000202 7f0320c8 7f032214 7f032110 8006b448 80a4b86c
[   11.230166] 7ec0: bdd17fa4 bdd17ed0 800141b0 8006b440 c0d4a000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   11.238357] 7ee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   11.246548] 7f00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 20000013 000da17d 76d96000 76f91d50
[   11.254741] 7f20: 00000080 8000fc44 bdd16000 00000000 bdd17fa4 bdd17f40 800a99e8 800a75e4
[   11.262935] 7f40: 8000faa4 bdfc0000 c0c70000 000da17d c0d146f8 c0d1455f c0d48a98 0000b758
[   11.271125] 7f60: 0000cf08 7f031e70 00000019 00000000 0000002c 0000002d 00000016 00000011
[   11.279319] 7f80: 0000000b 00000000 00000000 00000000 784fb200 784fd698 00000000 bdd17fa8
[   11.287509] 7fa0: 8000fa80 800a9940 00000000 784fb200 76d96000 000da17d 76f91d50 00000002
[   11.295699] 7fc0: 00000000 784fb200 784fd698 00000080 00000000 76f91d50 000da17d 00000000
[   11.303891] 7fe0: 00060000 7e936924 76f8bb07 76f0f264 60000010 76d96000 00000000 00000000
[   11.312074] Backtrace: 
[   11.314586] [<7f0290a0>] (inv_mpu_probe [inv_mpu_iio]) from [<8054ad94>] (i2c_device_probe+0xec/0x150)
[   11.323903]  r10:00000000 r9:00000004 r8:7f031798 r7:befd7800 r6:7f031798 r5:00000000
[   11.331840]  r4:befd7820
[   11.334417] [<8054aca8>] (i2c_device_probe) from [<8040e504>] (driver_probe_device+0x144/0x390)
[   11.343126]  r7:00000000 r6:80cf1758 r5:befd7820 r4:81589ca8
[   11.348882] [<8040e3c0>] (driver_probe_device) from [<8040e7f4>] (__driver_attach+0xa4/0xa8)
[   11.357328]  r10:00000000 r9:8152cc60 r8:7f037000 r7:00000000 r6:befd7854 r5:7f031798
[   11.365262]  r4:befd7820
[   11.367829] [<8040e750>] (__driver_attach) from [<8040c6fc>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x64/0x98)
[   11.376017]  r6:8040e750 r5:7f031798 r4:00000000 r3:bef307e4
[   11.381771] [<8040c698>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<8040de9c>] (driver_attach+0x28/0x30)
[   11.389783]  r6:80ccc070 r5:bdd2b480 r4:7f031798
[   11.394473] [<8040de74>] (driver_attach) from [<8040da60>] (bus_add_driver+0xf8/0x218)
[   11.402410] [<8040d968>] (bus_add_driver) from [<8040f1f0>] (driver_register+0x88/0x104)
[   11.410510]  r7:80cea230 r6:be7f95c0 r5:80c76c58 r4:7f031798
[   11.416264] [<8040f168>] (driver_register) from [<8054d384>] (i2c_register_driver+0x3c/0xfc)
[   11.424711]  r5:80c76c58 r4:7f031774
[   11.428362] [<8054d348>] (i2c_register_driver) from [<7f037018>] (inv_mpu_init+0x18/0x3c [inv_mpu_iio])
[   11.437764]  r5:80c76c58 r4:80c76c58
[   11.441414] [<7f037000>] (inv_mpu_init [inv_mpu_iio]) from [<80008b20>] (do_one_initcall+0xbc/0x204)
[   11.450554]  r4:80c76c58 r3:00000000
[   11.454193] [<80008a64>] (do_one_initcall) from [<800a92e0>] (load_module+0x1d08/0x235c)
[   11.462294]  r10:00000001 r9:8152cc60 r8:be7f9440 r7:80cea230 r6:7f0320c8 r5:7f0320d4
[   11.470230]  r4:bdd17f48
[   11.472799] [<800a75d8>] (load_module) from [<800a99e8>] (SyS_init_module+0xb4/0x124)
[   11.480638]  r10:00000000 r9:bdd16000 r8:8000fc44 r7:00000080 r6:76f91d50 r5:76d96000
[   11.488574]  r4:000da17d
[   11.491149] [<800a9934>] (SyS_init_module) from [<8000fa80>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[   11.499247]  r6:784fd698 r5:784fb200 r4:00000000
[   11.503937] Code: e28cc004 e2847b01 e5c435e5 e595e0b4 (e8be000f) 
[   11.510195] ---[ end trace fcf671f516c808ac ]---
udevd[324]: '/sbin/modprobe -b i2c:mpu9250' [333] terminated by signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
```

As far as I understand, it says segmentation error has occurred during `i2c device probe`. I am not able to find where I have done a mistake. As I have little knowledge about `dts file` I am not sure whether I have edited `dts file` correctly or not. And as far as the driver is concerned, it got compiled correctly so I feel driver should not be an issue here.

Please help me out. I have to finish off this task by this end of this week.

Thank you in advance for your reply.